# Check if field from .shp file exists in .csv file

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, fields-attributes, csv

[image: csv file with fields]

I have an output folder with .shp files and I want to check if the fields in the `.shp` files exist in a CSV document (one common CSV file for all shapefiles).

I go through the fields in the `.shp` files and check if they are not in the CSV file and when I want to delete them, they are not deleted.

Below I leave the code attached.

- `cell [2]` is the name of the field in the CSV file
- `fn[1:6]` is the `.shp` name file (`AC000.shp`) like in the CSV file

```py
with open(os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, csv_path)) as file:
    env.workspace = shape_files
    env.overwriteOutput = True
    shp_dict = {}
    csv_file= csv.reader(file)
    for shp in glob.glob(shp_process):
        fn = os.path.basename(shp)
        shp_dict[fn] = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(fn)]

    fields = arcpy.ListFields(fn)

    for cell in csv_file:
        for field in fields:
            if not field.name in cell[2] and fn[1:6] in csv_file :
                print field.name, cell[2]
```

Comment: Can you add contents of the csv file to your question (as text)?

Comment: I'll try to add a screen shot to the original post.

Comment: Edit your question and copy paste first 5 rows **as text**

Comment: Done. I edited the original post

Comment: You seem to want to delete something, but no deletion attempt is made.

Comment: Yes, I want to delete the fields from the shapefiles that are not in the csv file